# Python "TypeError" when writing to HTML File in "while" Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error

I have getting error for `TypeError: must be str, not int` This function below `new_file.write` works fine when it outside the while loop.

```
#write Data
i = 0
j = 0
while i < 10:
    i = i+1
    j = j+1
    news_file.write('<tr>\n' + '<th>' + i + '<\th>' + '\n')
    news_file.write('<th id="title"><a href="' + fetch_link[j] + '>' + fetch_title[j] + '</a></th>' + '\n' +'</tr>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python it is not possible to directly concat a string and non-strings. You'll have to use one of the many string interpolation syntaxes, for example:

```
news_file.write('<tr>\n<th>{}<\th>\n'.format(i)
```

Comment: I think I will stick with without loop for now.